# Reopening Word js-addin 'tries to open external app' confirmation dialog

Tags: ms-word, registry, office-js, custom-protocol

When I click on a hyperlink in my Word JS-addin that opens ms-word:// url, I get the following confirmation dialog:
[image: confirmation dialog]

However, when I check the checkbox and click on Cancel, I never get this dialog anymore and  cannot open MS-Word URL's from my addin anymore.

Where does Word keep my answer of this dialog? is there a registry key that I can clear in order to get the dialog again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try clean everything under C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef and try again?

update:
Try delete everything under registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF`

Comment: I have done that already, didn't help unfortunately:(

Comment: @user1971430 could you try my updated method? it is likely to be stored under Protocols of the WEF directory as per experts

Comment: Interessting enough tried again and it worked now. I did kill Winword.exe, apparently it was still running without being visible. Maybe that was the reason it did not work in first try. Thanks a lot!